# Running Ubuntu 19.10 But phpinfo() shows v19.04

Tags: apache2, php, php7

In trying to get ImageMagick to work with HEIC, I noticed that while I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed, phpinfo() shows version 19.04. This makes it difficult to know which php.ini to edit, especially as there is a PHP 7.2 folder and a 7.3 folder with phpinfo() reporting that the php.ini is in 7.2.

To add to the confusion, running *php -v* at the command line shows the expected versions, not the earlier versions shown in phpinfo. How does one get all this into sync and remove the older unused versions?

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.12-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:38:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.12, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.12-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I would not trust the PHP report from `phpinfo()` to state the proper Ubuntu version, since those version(s) are included in the version strings when you have multiple packages in repos of the same version.  We'd need to see a screenshot of the *exact* thing you're looking at to give you a better answer, but it's probably a version string in the package and not PHP specifically stating you're on 19.04 (just that the installed PHP7.2 package was originally packaged FOR 19.04)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I posted the answer, or at least AN answer, that seems to have solved the mismatch. Other postings I read said that what phpinfo() shows is what PHP sees and that Aoache2 doesn't interface with the command line in any way and that makes sense but still I needed PHP to see and use the latest version. I'm not sure how it got out of sync but it may be that the PHP version that I originally installed was not appropriate as I believe it was the CLI version and I'm not sure of the significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as I posted, I came across the answer which is to disable one PHP version and enable the other.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
Module php7.2 disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2

systemctl restart apache2

sudo a2enmod php7.3
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.3:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.3:
Enabling module php7.3.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2

systemctl restart apache2
```

Now phpinfo() shows the proper PHP version and the proper Ubuntu version. To remove the older version, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php7.2*'
```